# Set breakpoints on all references in IDA

Tags: ida, idapython

Is there a way to set breakpoints on all references in one click like we do in OllyDBG "Set breakpoint on every reference" ?

E.g: after locating CreateFileA API and pressing "x" to see all references, we can see where all calls for this function are ... but is there a way to set bps on all calls in one click ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about existence of such an ability in IDA, but you can do it with IDAPython as follows:

```
#I didn't check this code, use carefully, beware of errors

import idc
import idaapi
import idautils

def set_breakpoints_on_calls(ea):
    print "Setting breakpoints on ", hex(ea)
    for ref in idautils.CodeRefsTo(ea, 0):
        print "Adding bpt on ", hex(ref)
        idc.AddBpt(ref)

def set_breakpoints_on_screen_ea():
    print "Started"
    set_breakpoints_on_calls(idc.ScreenEA())

idaapi.add_hotkey("Alt-Z", set_breakpoints_on_screen_ea)
```

By running this code from execute script window you are adding hotkey Alt-Z
which sets breakpoints to all calls to the address where cursor is located.
You can add this code to `idapythonrc.py` file in IDA root folder to make this shortcut persistent (you'll need to rerun IDA after it).